# throttling bandwidth for a specific app

Tags: networking, ubuntu, bandwidth, slack

I only use `slack` in linux for chats and messages, not for calls. Yet, I see it eating my network bandwidth to a crazy level for past few days. It may be having something in the background or maybe it's a bug, but, in any case, if I could use something to throttle the bandwidth that it uses, it would be great. I don't think it would delay chat messages, but my overall system's performance would be saved.  Is there a way to do this(GUI tools would be preferred, but anything available would be helpful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **tc** command in conjunction with **iptables** to implement QOS/throttling for specific traffic. It requires the **iproute2** package I believe. (It's been a while)

I'm not sure if a gui has been implemented to do this task, it might be worth looking for a script or gui app to configure this if you aren't comfortable with configuring tc or iptables from the command prompt.

I would recommend going over the man-pages for both until you feel comfortable with both utilities.
It may not be a bad idea to practice on a VM first.

[www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/amp/](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/amp/)
You should be able to use some examples like in the link, and modify them to do what you need.

The other option, would be to implement QOS on the router level, this would probably be the much easier route. It depends on the router you are using, and the firmware that's running on it. (It has to have support for it in the router OS)

~Regards